# Como chamar um chave estrangeira?

Tags: php, mysql

Galera eu tenho uma plataforma que tem uma página para adicionar pessoa e noutra página tem para adicionar um plano a uma pessoa. Ou seja, primeiro cria um pessoa, e só depois é possível adicionar um plano. 
O meu problema é ligar um plano com uma pessoa. Eu na tabela de plano tenho a chave estrangeira da tabela de pessoa. Agora na página do plano eu precisava de referir o Id da pessoa em algum lado só não sei onde.

O Código do plano está assim, onde posso chamar a chave estrangeira (pessoa) no meio disto tudo visto que o plano é inserido em duas tabelas distintas mas a chave estrangeira aparece na tblplano?

```
 <?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
    {   
header('location:index.php');
}
else{
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$concretizaobj=$_POST['PerConObj'];
$objdefinidos=$_POST['ObjDef'];
$objatingidos=$_POST['ObjAting'];
$totalalcancados=$_POST['PerAlc'];
$datainicio=$_POST['DataInicial'];
$datafim=$_POST['DataFinal'];
$avalexp=$_POST['AvalExp'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblplano (PerConObj, ObjDef, ObjAting, PerAlc, DataInicial, DataFinal, AvalExp, ) VALUES(:concretizaobj, :objdefinidos, :objatingidos, :totalalcancados, :datainicio, :datafim, :avalexp)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':concretizaobj', $concretizaobj, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':objdefinidos', $objdefinidos, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':objatingidos', $objatingidos, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':totalalcancados', $totalalcancados, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':datainicio', $datainicio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':datafim', $datafim, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':avalexp', $avalexp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$id1 = $dbh->lastInsertId();

for($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
$avinicial=$_POST['AvInicial'][$i];
$meta=$_POST['Meta'][$i];
$avintercalar=$_POST['AvIntercalar'][$i];
$avfinal=$_POST['AvFinal'][$i];
$resultadouni=$_POST['Resultado'][$i];
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblobjetivos(tblplano_plano_id, AvInicial, Meta, AvIntercalar, AvFinal,Resultado) VALUES(:id1, :avinicial, :meta, :avintercalar, :avfinal, :resultadouni)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':id1', $id1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':avinicial', $avinicial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':meta', $meta, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':avintercalar', $avintercalar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':avfinal', $avfinal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':resultadouni', $resultadouni, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();


    if($lastInsertId)
    {
    $msg="PII Adicionado Com Sucesso!";
    }
    else 
    {
    $error="Erro, tente novamente";
    }}}
?>
```

Não sei se está fácil de entender mas é o seguinte, a tabela pessoa é constituída por informações pessoais, todas as pessoas têm um plano e cada plano tem vários objetivos. Porém para eu avisar que o plano é de uma pessoa deverei fazer referência no código do ID da pessoa certo? Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Tem que criar um select que contem as pessoas(id) na pagina dos planos, mas por que você não utiliza uma referencia na pessoa ao plano?

Comment: @LucasGauna eu tenho uma chave estrangeira referente à pessoa dentro do plano. Mas em código php não sei como a utilizar

Comment: Consegue enviar o banco (estrutura desses dois) só para termos uma noção melhor de como ele está?